Machine Learning Algorithm for identifying the factors contributing to academic performance of students
I have a dataset with several qualitative and quantitative attributes, including age, location (longitude, latitude), city, parent occupation, family size, GPA etc.
My task is to find the attributes/factors that contribute the highest towards the academic performance of the students. Which machine learning algorithm is the most suitable for this task?
A friend suggested using clustering algorithm that can segment the students into different performance groups, but I think that will not solve my problem.
